# How to get all hierarchy settings for all users in an org into apex code?

Tags: apex, customsetting

Is there any way to get ALL records of hierarchy custom settings for ALL Users/profiles in apex code and display it as a list on a custom page(lightning component) along with the user/profile names? Say for example, I have hierarchy custom setting defined for 3 users A, B, C and 1 for "Sales" profile . So I want to get a list of these custom setting records as:

A & respective field values,
B & respective field values,
C & respective field values,
Profile & respective field values,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this "for free" using the available methods (getInstance/getValues/getOrgDefaults), but you can query for them. I'd probably do something like the following.

```
@AuraEnabled global static CustomSetting__c[] getCustomSettings() {
    return [SELECT SetupOwner.Name, SetupOwner.Type, Name ...
            FROM CustomSetting__c
            ORDER BY SetupOwner.Type, SetupOwner.Name];
           ];
}
```

Replace CustomSetting__c with the correct name, and fill in additional fields for the ... in the field list.